# ssh tunneling with certification: how?

Tags: security, ssl, ssh, tunnel, tunneling

I have been through some basics about setting up SSH tunneling via e.g., putty. 
One question: how to let the two SSH ends authenticate each other based on certificate?
For example, using SSH tunneling for remote VNC access...

```
VNC == SSH (A) ===== SSH (B) === VNC
```

I want A and B to authenticate each other. It is arguable that VNC could have its own password for protection. But that is not the point here. I could have many apps running on A and B that are not necessarily having usr/pwd protection.

I check the putty config, seems no option for using certificate. Someone suggests stunnel, but I would like to see if doable using SSH directly. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any particular reason you need to use certificates, and not just ssh keys? The only reason I'm aware of is it takes the burden off of the host administrator from managing a complex configuration of `authorized_keys` files on hosts which have a lot of users who login.

OpenSSH introduced certificates in version 5.4, so make sure you're running at least that version on the server side. The client must support SSH certificates as well, and it is unclear to me at this moment if putty supports it. It does support ssh keys however, and unless you specifically need certificates, key-based authentication should be all you need.

Here is a good read on SSH certificates: http://blog.habets.pp.se/2011/07/OpenSSH-certificates

If you just need way to login without being prompted for a password, then just use ssh keys (which is what certificates use anyway).

You say this:

> I want A and B to authenticate each other.

Whether you use keys or certificates, you get this already out of the ssh protocol itself. When the client connects to the server, it compares the host key to it's local `known_hosts` files. If it's the first time you've ever going to that server, it asks you if you want to accept it. If the server's key changed since you logged in, you get the Man-in-the-middle warning, and based on your client configuration, asks you whether it's OK to proceed or simply doesn't let you continue.

This is the process of the server authenticating itself to the client, which happens before the client attempts to authenticate to the server.

Comment: Thank you very much. For server authentication, certificate is "stronger" than the host key (and arguably more convenient). For client authentication, certificate provides "less-coupled" mechanism: you don't need to set up user account or copy public key file onto server, which is suitable in a more peer-to-peer kind of scenario (as needed for my job). Before that, I use SSL certification process plus my own tcp-tunneling code. With SSH, I would like to see if the latter part could be avoided. Any idea?

Comment: Like I said, easier for the administrator, particularly on large setups. I would argue that it isn't a stronger method, but that is neither here nor there. As far as what you're trying to do, both A and B authenticate to each other. What is the second part of the question?

Comment: I think I have better understanding of SSH now from your help. Thanks again.